# UITableViewCell - When are the bounds properly set in iOS 10

Tags: uitableview, ios10, swift2

I want to create a round UIView (myView) inside a UITableViewCell

Prior to iOS 10 I was using `func awakeFromNib()` to do so like that:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var myView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()

      print(myView.bounds.height)
      myView.layer.cornerRadius = myView.bounds.height/2
      myView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

`myView` height and with are set to *30* via an AutoLayout constraint in my storyboard.

But `print(myView.bounds.height)` show *1000.0* in the console.
So the corner radius instruction set a radius to *500* and `myView` disappear completely.

Is the `UITableViewCell` life cycle change in iOS 10 ?
Is the function where the view.bounds are set change in iOS 10 ?
How can do a set a `cornerRadius` to half my view height in iOS 10 ?

[Here is a minimal projet to reproduce the issue](http://www.filedropper.com/testcornerradius)

To have a result close to what I want I need to add in my `UITableViewController`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But I'm quite sure this is not optimal ...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found two ways to fix it. Both enforce the cell to layout subviews

First solution:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.setNeedsLayout()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
```

Second way:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
      cell.setNeedsLayout()
      cell.layoutIfNeeded()
return cell
}
```

Comment: Second way worked for me. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, with the same size of *1000.0* when asking for the bounds of a subview.

As the *frame* or *bounds* values are not reliable anymore I had to declare an IBOutlet for the height constraint defined in my storyboard and use it to set the corner radius of my subview.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var myView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var myViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        print(myView.bounds.height)
        myView.layer.cornerRadius = myViewHeightConstraint.constant / 2
        myView.layer.masksToBounds = true
      }
}
```

This will enable you to remove the `reloadData` call which is really not optimal as you said.

Comment: Yes I use this solution too, It work ..., But It is still a work around for me :/

Comment: Kind of, yes, but it is the most efficient one as it does not require any reloading or relayout which can be costly.

Answer (score 0):

My observation is that iOS 10 / TVOS 10 is not laying out auto layout based views before calling awakeFromNib, but is laying out views using autoresizing masks before calling the same method.

Removing auto layout constraints and using the new Autoresizing settings in storyboards solved it for me.

[image: Autoresizing settings]

To me this makes Autolayout less reliable than autoresizing masks. I also 'feel' a performance improvement after switching out of Autolayout. I cannot say for sure though as I am on TVOS and the Core Animation instrument doesn't work for TVOS.